# Automount encrypted disk on demand with systemd using interactive passphrase

Tags: systemd, cryptsetup

I try to automount an LUKS encrypted disk with *systemd* on demand with in interactive passphrase. I am using a plain Debian without any window manager etc. I have configured `crypttab` and `fstab` "accordingly".

Extract of `crypttab`:

```
TEST  UUID=0fb1fe7c-2fa1-4c63-b8c6-ff702d5017a0  none  luks,noauto
```

Extract of `fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/TEST  /mnt/TEST  auto  noauto,x-systemd.automount  0  2
```

It works if `systemd-cryptsetup@TEST.service` is started manually:
The passphrase is prompted on the current (virtual) terminal. **I would expect the same behaviour if mounted on demand (accessing the mount point).**

Problems arise with the interactive passphrase prompt if triggered by corresponding **.automount systemd unit*:
`systemd-ask-password-wall.service` seems to be used (obviously triggered by corresponding `*.path` unit) which leads to an informative *wall message* and I need to spawn another shell to run `systemd-tty-ask-password-agent` manually.

If I disable both `systemd-ask-password-wall.*` units and try to run `systemd-tty-ask-password-agent` manually, it works neither with argument `--wall` nor `--console`, but only with plain `systemd-tty-ask-password-agent`.

Furthermore, the passphrase prompt just appears (and even get processed) if I stop `systemd-ask-password-wall.service`. It's acting confusing...

### TL;DR

1. Who has pulled `systemd-ask-password-wall.path` in?
2. How to switch to `systemd-ask-password-console.path` (if that works) or to a homebrown unit?
3. Why does this not work out of the box? What is the difference from starting `systemd-cryptsetup@TEST.service` manually?
4. Is there a cleaner (more canonical) way of doing this?

---

Regarding question 3: I guess in that case the passphrase agent is started somehow differently.

Regarding question 4: I did not investigate *udev* right now, but just wanted to ge it working with *systemd* on the first try.